# CoreData + Cloudkit fetch() after app uninstall/reinstall returns no results

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I am attempting to configure CoreData+CloudKit using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` to automatically sync data to/from CloudKit.

Following [the Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/), it was trivial enough to set up an Entity, add the appropriate capabilities in Xcode, set up the `persistentContainer` and `saveContext` in my AppDelegate.

I'm making `fetch()` and `save()` calls through the `NSManagedObjectContext`, and I'm able to save and fetch records without issue.  I can see them in the CloudKit dashboard.

However, if I uninstall the app from the simulator and rebuild/reinstall, my `fetchRequest` (which has no `NSPredicate` or sorting, just fetching all records) is always returning an empty list. I'm using the same iCloud account, and I've tried both the public and private database scope. If I create a new record and then retry my fetch request I can retrieve that newly created record, but never any of the old records. I'm 100% certain these records are still in the CloudKit database, as I can see them on the CloudKit Dashboard web app.

I took a look at [Apple's CoreDataCloudKitDemo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/synchronizing_a_local_store_to_the_cloud) app, and it is able to fetch "Post" entities from the CloudKit database after an uninstall/reinstall, so I know it is possible. However, it is using an `NSFetchedResultsController`, which won't work for my application (mine is a SpriteKit game).

I attempted copying my CoreData+Cloudkit code into a brand new Xcode project and I can reproduce this issue there. Here's my code for reference:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        // Create a container that can load CloudKit-backed stores
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "coredatacloudkitexample")

        // Enable history tracking and remote notifications
        guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
            fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to retrieve a persistent store description.")
        }
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        description.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (_, error) in
            guard let error = error as NSError? else { return }
            fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to load persistent stores:\(error)")
        })

        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        container.viewContext.transactionAuthor = "nibbler"

        // Pin the viewContext to the current generation token and set it to keep itself up to date with local changes.
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        do {
            try container.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
        } catch {
            fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to pin viewContext to the current generation:\(error)")
        }

        return container
    }()
}


// ------

import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let viewContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
        let people: [Person]

        do {
            people = try viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            print("---> fetched People from CoreData: \(people)")

            // people.isEmpty is ALWAYS true (empty array) on first install of app, even if records exist in table in CloudKit
            if people.isEmpty {
                let person = Person(context: viewContext)
                person.name = "nibbler"

                // save the data through managed object context
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                    print("--> created Person in CoreData: \(person)")
                } catch {
                    print("---> failed to save Person: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("---> error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Why can I only fetch the records created during this app's install and not prior ones?

**UPDATE**: It seems that if I wait for a few seconds and re-try my fetch on the first app install that I **am** able to retrieve the results from the CloudKit database. I can also see a vast number of `CoreData+CloudKit` log messages in the console upon first launch. Here's what I'm thinking -- even when using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`, a `fetch()` is reading/writing to the local CoreData store, and then a separate process is running in the background to mirror and merge the local CoreData records with the CloudKit records.

As such, I believe I need to somehow wait/be notified that this sync/merge of local CoreData and CloudKit records has completed on first launch before making my `fetch()` call, rather than making the `fetch()` call immediately as the app opens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `NSFetchedResultsController`, why do you think it wouldn't work for your application?

The reason it is necessary is `NSFetchedResultsController` monitors the `viewContext` and when the sync process downloads new objects and inserts them into a background context the `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` merges the objects in to the `viewContext` and advances the generation token. The FRC's delegate methods are called to notify you if objects are inserted, updated or deleted from the fetched objects array which are objects in the context that match the fetch request's entity and predicate.

Comment: As I understood the `NSFetchedResultsController` from apple's documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller) this controller is to be used in conjunction with a table view controller. Since I have a SpriteKit game, I'm using CoreData to store game state information (points, currency, rank, etc), and I'm not working with a table view controller. This data just provides persistent state for my game so someone can pick up where they left off, regardless of device. Are you suggesting NSFetchedResultsController is a fine solution for this too?

Comment: Yes it fine solution.

Comment: I've tried this out, and it does seem to mostly solve my issue, so thank you very much for the response. The one thing I'm wondering is how is best to know, when I'm truly in sync with CloudKit? In the FRC delegate method `didChangeContentWith snapshot`, I;m not sure how to know if this snapshot is the data I'm interested in. Can I just assume as soon as this delegate method is called on first app open that now my local CoreData store is synced with CloudKit, or do I need to do something more sophisticated to inspect the snapshot data?

Comment: You can experiment with the snapshots but personally I feel it is not ready yet. For example, on the performFetch the snapshot changed delegate method is called inline which is highly unusual and in a lot of peoples' code I see them in fact miss that and instead create their own snapshot from the fetchedObjects which is of course the wrong format compared to the didChange provided snapshot. iOS 14 didChange snapshot includes reloads for changes which I also find strange. Please try the old didChangeContent and use fetchedObjects. Then you could try didChangeObject for sprite delta updates.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is this the "old" `didChangeContent` delegate method you are referring to as the delegate method I should use? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate/1622290-controllerdidchangecontent -- also, when using the `NSFetchedResultsController`, is the proper way to fetch objects to use the `didChangeObject` delegate method to be informed of changes, rather than making fetch requests?

Comment: Yes that didChangeContent will tell you when the fetchedObjects has been updated, when a change happens after the initial performFetch is done. The only reason to do another performFetch is if you edit the predicate or sort descriptors on the fetchRequest. didChangeObject is called for each change to the fetchedObjects array, inserted, deleted etc. You can use that to make the edits to your sprite. Or you can just update the entire sprite with fetchedObjects in didChangeContent.

Comment: Great, perfect explanation. TY again. One final question: when launching the app for the first time (or after deleting/reinstalling), how is best to know that there truly are no results after calling `performFetch()`? `controller.fetchedObjects` may be empty if CloudKit mirroring hasn't happened yet. If the fetch has no matching objects in CoreData+CloudKit, the `didChangeContent` (and all) delegate methods are never called. I could just create the record at the point where I first need to write to it if I haven't been able to fetch it, but I may end up with duplicate records if fetch is slow

Comment: Sadly there is no way to create a default object with a specific record ID, so that you could create it on app first run, and then if one comes down from the cloud it could merge it. Instead, you could try what Apple do in their sample with their deduplicate tags routine. I expect though that'll wreak havoc with related data.

Comment: I think I found a way to determine if the default object exists in CloudKit database. I am making a query to CloudKit directly using the public or private database if the CoreData managed object context has no objects. Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is this:

- Set `NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions`

```swift
let id = "iCloud.yourid"  
let options = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: id)  
description?.cloudKitContainerOptions = options
```

- Initialize your CloudKit schema (this is required at least once)

```swift
do {
     try container.initializeCloudKitSchema()
  } catch {
    print("ERROR \(error)")
 }
```

Edit:
Can you change `lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer`

to `lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @stamenkovski! I tried both of these just now and see the same behavior, unfortunately :( fetch returning empty array on first install.

Comment: I edited my answer. Also make sure you don't call initializeCloudKitSchema everytime you install the application.

Comment: I tried s/NSPersistentCloudKitContainer/NSPersistentContainer as you suggested and the same behavior is observed. I also checked, and since NSPersistentCloudKitContainer subclasses NSPersistentContainer, and since this is just a type hint for the compiler I believe it is functionally equivalent.

Comment: Yes, understood about only invoking `initializeCloudKitSchema` once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing @professormeowingtons you mention whenever you delete the app on simulator you it won't show the previous records, so my suggestion is to try your app on a real device with an iCloud account already configured, that way you'll be able to add some records to your db then delete the app, reinstall and fetch all the previous records you did enter.

Comment: I have tried this just now, and see the same behavior on a real device as I see on the simulator. The first fetch on first install still returns empty array.